# SSH X11 Forwarding and Graphical Application Loading

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, x11-forwarding, openbsd

The Symptoms are as follows.

If an application creates a new window, the window will take ages to load. The host machine has a leased line and I have 1.4 MB (Bytes not bits) up and downstream from the X server machine. The connection is routed as follows.

X-Server -> internet gateway box(SSH 2022:xclient-machine:22) -> Xclient-machine (SSH)

i.e., I am going through a Openbsd box using a SSH tunnel to get to my client machine where the X11 forwarding is happening

When I create a remote gnome-terminal it can take anywhere between a minute to five minutes. If I use one of these remote terminals to create a new gnome terminal, that too takes the same time, furthermore the terminal that initiated the new window is locked during this time.

Other then this the windows are perfectly responsive. What might be going on here ?

Note1: This is not a compression or bandwidth issue.

Note2: The remote client machine has "UseDns no" set in the sshd config.

Note3: performing a reverse DNS(nslookup) lookup of my home address, or that of the external ip of the gateway machine, results in a immediate response. The gateway IP does not have a FQDN.

What is going on here ? Do I need to setup FreeNX ?

Comment: Have you tried to use a simple xterm? gnome-terminal may start a lot of useless gnome-daemons and services, which may cause DNS lookups etc.

Answer (score 0):

X11 Forwarding is a waste of time in this day and age. Just use the free version of no machine. It can configured and set-up, both client and server, within 10 minutes.

Comment: NX uses X11 forwarding over SSH, so that "waste of time" is what lets your "solution" work.

Comment: I thought it comes with bunch of libraries that override or optimize native X11 behaviour ?